With lsp-mode for C#, how can I replace var with explicit type?
In Visual Studio, there is a Quick Action to use explicit type instead of 'var'.
Is this Quick Action supposed to be available using lsp-mode?
I've tried lsp-execute-code-action, but it doesn't suggest replacing var.
